# Ways to optimize Flink S3 checkpointing performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink S3 backend for checkpointing. We have a state size of ~100-200GB with incremental checkpointing. We have job parallelism of ~5k with 3 operators(kinesis consumer operator(750), state machine operator(3.5K parallelism) and S3 sink(450)). I am using s3-presto library for Checkpointing and s3-hadoop for S3 sink

Initially I was facing multiple S3 socket timeout and S3 throttling Exceptions. To fix that, I have added following in flink configs:

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://prod-flink-test-checkpoint/_entropy_/flink/checkpoints
state.backend.incremental: true
s3.connection.maximum: 1000
s3.entropy.key: _entropy_
s3.entropy.length: 8
state.storage.fs.memory-threshold: 1000000
state.backend.fs.write-buffer-size: 4194304
presto.s3.socket-timeout: 1m
presto.s3.connect-timeout: 1m
presto.s3.max-connections: 6000
```

Post adding entropy and socket timeout configs, all socket timeout exceptions went away but I am still seeing S3 throttling. Another new issue I am seeing is delay in triggering checkpoint. I have configured 70sec checkpoint interval and but in Flink dashboard and job manager logs, I am seeing it is getting triggered in 10-40 mins delay.

```
checkpoint-interval : 70000
min-pause-between-checkpoint : 15000
max-concurrent-checkpoint : 1
checkpoint-type: aligned
Aligned-checkpoint-timeout : 30sec
TolerableCheckpointFailureNumber :2
Checkpoint-mode : atleast-once
```

Any idea why this is happening or how should I debug? I am not seeing any major backpressure in job and there is no other exceptions visible in job manager logs

S3 throttling Exception with entropy

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: java.io.IOException: Could not flush to file and close the file system output stream to s3://prod-flink-test-checkpoint/DHpRvkE8/flink/checkpoints/6ddf92e0c7902eba815543fca2fa2730/chk-6/d78e8ca4-2ec8-4732-86f2-7a3b85df2637 in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:425) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DuplicatingCheckpointOutputStream.closeAndGetPrimaryHandle(DuplicatingCheckpointOutputStream.java:260) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.CheckpointStreamWithResultProvider$PrimaryAndSecondaryStream.closeAndFinalizeCheckpointStreamResult(CheckpointStreamWithResultProvider.java:113) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapSnapshotStrategy.lambda$asyncSnapshot$3(HeapSnapshotStrategy.java:181) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SnapshotStrategyRunner$1.callInternal(SnapshotStrategyRunner.java:91) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.SnapshotStrategyRunner$1.callInternal(SnapshotStrategyRunner.java:88) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AsyncSnapshotCallable.call(AsyncSnapshotCallable.java:78) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtils.java:540) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:54) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsyncCheckpointRunnable.finalizeNonFinishedSnapshots(AsyncCheckpointRunnable.java:191) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(AsyncCheckpointRunnable.java:124) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: P947AG455MJ7TQB0; S3 Extended Request ID: VquhT/jyfuuLLjuJiFfrCCrXSMPw8fmkHGavMJfvMV/n2ENSENtQrhTJZ1B15n8s3PNDu5fsbAI=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: VquhT/jyfuuLLjuJiFfrCCrXSMPw8fmkHGavMJfvMV/n2ENSENtQrhTJZ1B15n8s3PNDu5fsbAI=
```

Comment: The `flink-s3-fs-presto` library is recommended for checkpointing over the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` one, see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/ - Have you tried that one already?

Comment: I would start by trying presto, as @MartijnVisser suggested. But you could also try increasing `state.storage.fs.memory-threshold`, which will reduce the number of files being written. And you could try using the changelog state backend.

Comment: Thanks a lot(@DavidAnderson, @MartijnVisser) for the suggestions. I tried replacing hadoop with presto library, but getting multiple checkpoint failures with "Failure Message: Asynchronous task checkpoint failed". Flink exception dashboard is not showing any Exception stack trace. Is it some known issue with presto library?
Failure rate is ~40% and it is happening intermittently

Comment: Attached screenshot in question

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I have updated the question with new configs I tried to improve S3 checkpointing